# in pygame is it possible to detect when a key is pressed?

Tags: pygame, detection

i am working on a game where you need to press keys
however, i know how to detect the up arrow keys and space etc
but i don't know how to detect lowercase letters.
I'm sorry it sounds like a silly thing to ask.

Answer (score 0):

we can use the is_pressed() function in python to detect key presses. It's in the keyboards module. The is_pressed() takes a character as input and returns True if the key with the same character is pressed on the keyboard